# How can I write a line of code for p5.js that works as a camera follower for my player? (var Mover;) This is a 2D game

Tags: javascript, camera, 2d, p5.js

https://editor.p5js.org/LttntLark/sketches/JBSg2zIfEf

All the code is above.
I've been trying to make a camera that follows the player(Mover), and it says I need WEBGL. Is there a way to do this without it in p5.js? I've searched up tutorials, and nothing says I can make a "camera" for p5 in 2d, and that  I "NEED WEBGL" And I cant remodel my game in WEBGL, so I need a code that is a "viewport" that keeps my player centered on the screen while he moves.

Comment: _"...and it says I need WEBGL."_ camera() is a 3D WebGL function, so it will ask you for WebGL because it's well, a WebGL function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable WebGL mode, add WEBGL to your `createCanvas()`

Example:

```js
createCanvas(1500, 2560, WEBGL);
```

Comment: Do i NEED webgl?
My follow mouse behaviour acts up if i turn it on

Comment: I would suggest looking up how to use WebGL with p5.js, especially since if what you are doing says ' I "NEED WEBGL" '

Comment: I was just saying that everything i look up says i need it, and i was asking if theres a way to make a follow player camera without it

Comment: You can use the `translate(x, y);` function. Make sure you run `push();`  before the translate and `pop();` after it. Just set that translate_x to be the x position of the player plus half of the width of the player, and the translate_y to be the y position of the player plus half of the player height

Comment: Im bad with word problems, what would that look like?

Comment: @LttntLrk [This video by The Coding Train aka Daniel Shiffman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXuxYMGe4KI) shows him creating an agario clone, using the translate() function, and also creating the web server. this is an old tutorial so he doesn't use ES6+ syntax, but still good to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Let WIDTH be the canvas width
    // Let HEIGHT be the canvas height
    // Let player be the center of perspective (with x and y positions)

    function draw() {
      // Do not push/pop
      // This line of code should affect all drawing below
      //
      translate(WIDTH / 2 - player.x, HEIGHT / 2 - player.y);
      //
      // This line translate the camera making the player always centered



      /////////////////
      //
      // Your other drawings here
      //
      /////////////////
    }
```